# Acciones asíncronas en MVC se comportan como síncronas al habilitar Session_Start en Global.asax

Tags: asp.net, mvc

Se crea una aplicación en blanco para MVC 5.2.3 y .Net Framework 4.5.2 desde Visual Studio 2015. Se implementa un controlador con métodos asíncronos que permiten ver el progreso (*GetProgressAsync*) de una supuesta tarea larga en el servidor (*CommitAsync*):

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public static int Progress = 0;

    public async Task<ActionResult> GetProgressAsync()
    {
        Task<ActionResult> task = Task.Run<ActionResult>(() =>
        {
            var result = new ContentResult();
            result.Content = string.Format("Progreso: {0}", Progress);
            return result;
        });

        return await task;
    }

    public async Task<ActionResult> CommitAsync()
    {
        Task<ActionResult> task = Task.Run<ActionResult>(() =>
        {
            Progress = 0;

            while (Progress < 100)
            {
                Progress++;
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
            }

            var result = new ContentResult();
            result.Content = string.Format("{0} : Commit completado", DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString());
            return result;
        });

        return await task;
    }
}
```

Si en el archivo Global.asax.cs no se habilitan los métodos *Session_Start/Session_End*, el controlador funcionará en asíncrono como debe, es decir, se podrá ir consultando el progreso de la tarea (desde un navegador, por ejemplo).

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
    }

    //WARNING: habilitar estos métodos hace que no funcionen las llamadas Async/Await
    //WARNING: enabling this methods hang Async/Await support
    //protected void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    //{
    //    // TODO
    //}

    //protected void Session_End(object sender, EventArgs e)
    //{
    //    // TODO
    //}
}
```

El problema ocurre cuando se habilitan los métodos de sesión. El controlador sólo funcionará en asíncrono la primera vez. Las siguientes peticiones que se hagan a CommitAsync bloquearán la aplicación y llamadas a *GetProgressAsync* no serán despachadas hasta que *CommitAsync* no termine su tarea.

Comment: lograste solucionarlo?

Answer (score 1):

Hay que poner el siguiente atributo en el controller:

```
[SessionState(SessionStateBehavior.ReadOnly)]
```

Al parecer, el uso de la sesión bloquea peticiones de un mismo cliente cuando está realizando las labores de deserialización de la misma...